# Listen to RADIUS attributes sent to a peer

Tags: debian, freeradius

Using here Debian Stretch 9.1 with FreeRadius 3.0.15.

I need to be able to listen to a transmission to a Radius peer, that has a secret (known by me).

I have tried to do:

```
radsniff -f "host 1.1.1.1"
```

and

```
radsniff -f "host 1.1.1.1" -ssecret
```

However both tries are not showing the RADIUS attributes I need to see. What to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct format to use is:

```
 radsniff -f "host 1.1.1.1" -ssecret  -x
```

It seems in the past "-x" was the default behaviour, hence my confusion.

From `man freeradius`

> -x     Print out debugging information.